# VMWare serial connection between two vm hosts

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, serial

I am attempting to simulate a serial connection between two VMWare virtual machines running CentOS 6.3; both hosted on the same VMWare vSphere 5.1.0 host (linux based ).

Googling yielded [these instructions](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50%2FGUID-A779C84D-4324-4D32-AF43-BBD962ABC9E3.html) and it seems that the named-pipe solution is what I want; but the given instructions didn't work for me:  no pipe is created on the host, nor the guest VM, and no additional serial ports are available on the guest.

Further searches yielded [these instructions for workstation](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_devices_serial_2vms.html), which give some indication about what valid answers for the named pipe name.  When I attempt to enter a named pipe according to the instructions (using '/tmp/pipeName' as the pipe name) I get an error `Incompatible device backing for device '0'`.  Using a pipe name with no slashes does not produce the error, but still I get the original results -- the procedure "works" but no new pipes and/or serial ports are available on the guest.

When I add a serial port to a guest OS, how can I know what the port address/IRQ will be?

When I choose "Named Pipe", on what machine (host or guest) is that named pipe being created?  How do I map the named pipe back to a serial port?

Comment: Well those instructions are for VMware Workstation, not for vSphere 5.1.

Comment: There's similar (but less detailed) instructions for vSphere; I just linked to the ones that described more clearly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "named pipe name" that it's asking you to enter is really the name of the serial port you wish it to attach to.  In the case of COM1, `/dev/ttyS0` is the correct input.

I tested this by installing minicom (`yum install minicom`) on both VMs.  The default serial port for minicom is /dev/modem, which won't work, so I had to run `minicom -s` and change the serial configuration on both VMs to /dev/ttyS0.  Then, after opening minicom, anything typed into the terminal appears on the other terminal's output (terminal echo is off by default).