# Serial Connections between Virtual Servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-esxi

We have two applications on separate virtualized Windows servers use serial communication to each other. On the host, there are two serial to USB converters connected with a serial cable, and one of the converters mapped in VMware to each server.

We would like to do the communication over IP, so that the servers can be moved between clustered VMware hosts or be restored in another location easily.

The hypervisor is VMware ESXi, the servers are Windows Server 2008.

It is possible that the links in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/466326/vmware-serial-connection-between-two-vm-hosts) may lead to resolution. It is for Linux guests rather than Windows, and I am not certain how to implement it.

My hope is that someone here can suggest more straight-forward solution, or can give me some clues how to implement something in Windows.

Comment: Surely you mean ESXi?

Comment: It's late -- you are correct.